# How can I add attributes and functions to this ZeroMQ Class in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes, zeromq

So this works:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,a=1):
        Foo.a = a

    def Sna(self):
        print 'Yodel'
```

`F  = Foo()` followed by `F.a` returns 1, and `F.Sna()` prints `'Yodel'`.

But what if I want to add attributes and functions to a base/parent class? In this case a `Context` class from `ZeroMQ`? I don't understand the errors I'm getting.

```
from zmq import Context

class ZeroMQ(Context):
    def __init__(self,port=None,filt=None):
        super(ZeroMQ,self).__init__(self)
        self.port = port
        self.filt = filt
```

Here calling `F = ZeroMQ(50000,'Yodel')` returns an `AttributeError`:

```
/autonomy/toshi/zero_mq.pyc in __init__(self, port, filt)
     22         def __init__(self,port=None,filt=None):
     23                 super(ZeroMQ,self).__init__(self)
---> 24                 self.port = port
     25                 self.filt = filt
     26 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/sugar/attrsettr.pyc in __setattr__(self, key, value)
     24         except AttributeError:
     25             raise AttributeError("%s has no such option: %s" % (
---> 26                 self.__class__.__name__, upper_key)
     27             )
     28         else:

AttributeError: ZeroMQ has no such option: PORT
```

I have the feeling I am missing something simple and obvious...

Comment: Evidently the `Context` you've inherited from has a `__setattr__` method that prevents you from setting arbitrary attributes. Have you read its documentation?

Comment: What are you even trying to do here? Your class has `port` and `filt` members, yet all methods using such items take them as arguments, not from the class (in fact, `sub` and `pub` should be staticmethods). In addition, `ZeroMQ.sendX` calls `self.send` - `zmq.Context` does not have a `send` method, `zmq.Socket` does. "'localhost" is also not a valid port!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did here https://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html but didn't see anything -- but what you say makes some sense.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, it has some problems. I don't have much practice working with Classes. I fixed the port in the example call. You're also right about the `sendX`, I have cut it. Hopefully the question is pared down now.